# es6 module: is there a way to call a function by name?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a  function where I want to pass in the name of the member function it should execute:

```
const gen = (N, inFunc) => {  //inFunc = 'func1' or 'func2'
  const func1 = () => {...}
  const func2 = () => {...}

  let func = this[inFunc]  // doesn't work; no 'this' in an ES6 module

  newFunc = func();  // nice try
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Use an object that maps names to functions.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Side note: `this` is not determined by the fact the code runs in a module. But `this` is not going to help you, since `func1` and `func2` are not properties, but variables. They need to become properties.

Comment: There is no good way to refer to a local variable by name using a string.  Your `func1` and `func2` are local variables.  So, as the answer below shows, put them in an object so you can refer to the object property by name.  FYI, `this` has NOTHING at all to do with local variables - that's why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I don't get what this question has to do with ES6 modules. The functions `func1` and `func2` that you want to call are *local variables* in a *function* scope. They're neither module imports/exports nor in a module scope?!

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
const gen = (N, inFunc) => {
  const fns = {
    func1: () => {...}
    func2: () => {...}
  }

  let func = fns[inFunc]

  newFunc = func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. yep, **this** wasn't going to help with that ;-)
2. Konrad Linkowski's answer is fine, but I went a different route (suggested by barmar):

```
    const gen = (N, inFunc) => {  //inFunc = 'func1' or 'func2'
      const func1 = () => {...}
      const func2 = () => {...}
    
      const funcs = {
        func1, func2 }  
    
      let newFunc = funcs[inFunc]();  
    }
```